# Remove duplicates from array in linear time and without extra arrays

Tags: arrays

We have an array and it is unsorted. We know the range is [0,n].

We want to remove duplicates but we **cannot use extra arrays** and it must **run in linear time**.

Any ideas? Just to clarify, this is not for homework!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can do this to be honest. I mean there is counting sort, but that requires additional space.

Comment: I'm with Mimisbrunnr -- I'm not sure this can be done. Googling suggests that using a hashmap (which probably isn't allowed, here) is the fastest, easiest way to do it; If there were a clever, linear-time algorithm that didn't require extra memory it would be easy to find.

Comment: Is this an array of ints? Can you reorder the array?

Comment: Not language specific. Java would work, I suppose. By additional space regarding counting sort, I assume you mean buckets/arrays, yes? See I thought this couldn't be done either but the person who posed the question insists it can. I get the answer to it on Monday but I am just curious to know what the answer is before then, haha.

Comment: Yes, it is an array of ints. You can reorder the array as long as you finish with O(n) running time.

Comment: @Geoff is the range of integers limited 0..n? Or can it be any int?

Comment: We know that all integers in the array are between 0 and n.

Comment: @Geoff can you please delete your comments and add them into your question to clarify?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the integers are limited 0 to n, you can move through the array, placing numbers by their indices. Every time you replace a number, take the value that used to be there and move it to where it should be. For instance, let's say we have an array of size 8:

```
-----------------
|3|6|3|4|5|1|7|7|
-----------------
 S
```

Where S is our starting point, and we'll use C to keep track of our "current" index below.
We start with index 0, and move 3 to the 3 index spot, where 4 is. Save 4 in a temp var.

```
-----------------
|X|6|3|3|5|1|7|7|   Saved 4 
-----------------  
 S     C
```

We then put 4 in the index 4, saving what used to be there, 5.

```
-----------------
|X|6|3|3|4|1|7|7|   Saved 5
-----------------
 S       C
```

Keep going

```
-----------------
|X|6|3|3|4|5|7|7|   Saved 1
-----------------
 S         C

-----------------
|X|1|3|3|4|5|7|7|   Saved 6
-----------------
 S C

-----------------
|X|1|3|3|4|5|6|7|   Saved 7    
-----------------
 S           C
```

When we try to replace 7, we see a conflict, so we simply don't place it. We then continue from the starting index S, increment it by 1:

```
-----------------
|X|1|3|3|4|5|6|7| 
-----------------  
   S
```

1 is fine here, 3 needs to move

```
-----------------
|X|1|X|3|4|5|6|7|
-----------------
     S
```

But 3 is a duplicate, so we throw it away and keep iterating through the rest of the array.

So basically, we move each entry at most 1 time, and iterate through the entire array. That's O(2n) = O(n)

Comment: This requires additional space in some cases. What if you have { 0, 1, 20 } as your array? then you need an array of size 20.

Comment: You probably also need to do compression of the array at the end by removing items that are marked with X above (i.e. -1 could be used to mark missing items). To remove items just go through all elements once and copy to last free space O(n) again.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr Integers are limited from 0..n, where n is the size of the array

Comment: Or did I misread? I agree this won't work if n > the size of the array.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr - If I understand problem correctly, for an array of size 3, you can only have values in range [0,3].

Comment: @Jeff +1 - My solution is essentially the same as yours.

Comment: I think this would do it! Thanks Jeff & all.

Answer (score 3):

Assume `int a[n]` is an array of integers in the range [0,n-1].  Note that this differs slightly from the stated problem, but I make this assumption to make clear how the algorithm works. The algorithm can be patched up to work for integers in the range [0,n].

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if (a[i] != i)
    {
         j = a[i];
         k = a[j];
         a[j] = j;  // Swap a[j] and a[i]
         a[i] = k;
     }
 }

 for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
 {
     if (a[i] == i)
     {
        printf("%d\n", i);
     }
 }
```

Comment: in the second if it's an assignment operator instead of comparison

Answer (score 3):

```
    void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
  int i;
  printf("The repeating elements are: \n");
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if(arr[abs(arr[i])] >= 0)
      arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])];
    else
      printf(" %d ", abs(arr[i]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you sort? Sort with Radix Sort - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort with complexity O(arraySize) for given case and then remove duplicates from sorted array  O(arraySize).

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the array assign array[array[i]] = -array[array[i]]; if not negative; if its already negative then its duplicate, this will work since all values are within 0 and n.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Joel Lee's code for completion.

```
#include <iostream>
void remove_duplicates(int *a, int size)
{
  int i, j, k;
  bool swap = true;

   while(swap){
    swap = false;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(a[i] != i && a[i] != a[a[i]]){
            j = a[i];
            k = a[j];
            a[i] = k;
            a[j] = j;
            swap = true;      
        }

    }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    //int array[8] = {3,6,3,4,5,1,7,7};
    int array[8] = {7,4,6,3,5,4,6,2};

    remove_duplicates(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        if(array[i] == i)
            std::cout << array[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 I think this can be solved with only a few lines reducing the array into an object and then using object.keys to get array without duplicates. This probably takes more memory. I'm not sure.

I did it like this:

```
var obj = array.reduce(function (acc, elem) {
      acc[elem] = true;
      return acc;
    },{});
var uniqueArray = Object.keys(obj);
```

This has the added bonus (or disadvantage) of sorting the array. It works with strings too.

Comment: This definitely uses linear auxilliary space, which the questions asks not to

Answer (score 0):

Use the array a a container with negative sign as an indicator, this will corrupt the input though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).