# Duplicate removal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, duplicates

Let's be honest, this is a hw question.

The question in its entirety:

> Implement duplicate removal algorithm in a one-dimensional array using C++/Java in O(n) time complexity with no extra space. For example, if the input array is {3,5,5,3,7,8,5,8,9,9} then the output should be {3,5,7,8,9}.

I have thought about it for quite a while and haven't been able to solve it yet.

My thoughts:

1. I could remove duplicates in O(n) if the array was sorted. But the fastest sorting algorithm I know has O(n*log(n)) complexity.
2. One algorithm that sorts in O(n) is bin or bucket sort. The problem here is that it cannot be implemented without using extra space.
3. I wonder if it is possible at all.

I have researched a bit and have found nothing new.

Thanks for any help.

P.S.: I would have given it more time if it weren't for the exam tomorrow.

Comment: A hashtable can tell you in O(1) time whether or not an element exists in its set. That should point you in the right direction

Comment: However, a hashtable requires space and it says _with no extra space_.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Good point, I missed this part.

Comment: I have thought of O(n) solutions like using a `bool` array but that takes up space. I really need it done.

Comment: Unless elements are bounded, I don't think it is possible in O(n) without the additional space. If they are bounded, see this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414854/remove-duplicates-from-array-in-linear-time-and-without-extra-arrays

Comment: This sounds impossible without some extra assumptions.

Comment: The requirements to be O(1) in space and O(n) in time are really hard if not impossible. However, I found [an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533667/98607) that applies to integers and claims to be within these limits (at least in normal cases). It uses recursion however it can be done using a tail call to not require extra memory.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I'll see the post, Martin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed possible, just use [in-place radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#In-place_MSD_radix_sort_implementations).

It runs for `O(kn)` where `k` is constant for any standard numeric data type, and requires `O(1)` extra space.

Here`s the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/// in-place 32-bit recursive radix sort
void I32R(int32_t *data, uint32_t size, uint32_t nbit) {
    uint32_t dbgn = (uint32_t)-1, dend = size;

    while (++dbgn < dend)
        if (data[dbgn] & nbit)
            while (dbgn < --dend)
                if (~data[dend] & nbit) {
                    data[dbgn] ^= data[dend];
                    data[dend] ^= data[dbgn];
                    data[dbgn] ^= data[dend];
                    break;
                }
    if ((nbit >>= 1) && (dend > 1))
        I32R(data, dend, nbit);
    if (nbit && (size - dend > 1))
        I32R(data + dend, size - dend, nbit);
}

/// O_t(n) / O_s(1) duplicate remover
int32_t dups(int32_t *data, uint32_t size) {
    int32_t iter, *uniq = data;

    if (size < 2)
        return size;
    for (iter = 0; iter < size; iter++)
        data[iter] ^= (1 << 31);
    I32R(data, size, 1 << 31);
    data[0] ^= (1 << 31);
    for (iter = 1; iter < size; iter++)
        if (*uniq != (data[iter] ^= (1 << 31)))
            *++uniq = data[iter];
    return uniq - data + 1;
}

void parr(int32_t *data, uint32_t size) {
    for (; size; size--)
        printf("%4d%s", *data++, (size == 1)? "\n\n" : ", ");
}

int main() {
    int32_t iter, size, *data;

    data = malloc((size = 256) * sizeof(*data));
    for (iter = 0; iter < size; iter++)
        data[iter] = (int8_t)rand() & -3;
    parr(data, size);
    parr(data, dups(data, size));
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

**N.B.#1:** inverting the sign bit before sorting is necessary for positive numbers to become greater than negatives, as radix sort only operates on unsigned values.

**N.B.#2:** this is just a rough illustration, never really tested.

**N.B.#3:** oh wow, this is actually faster than `qsort()`!

**N.B.#4:** and now there`s a non-recursive version of the sorting function; the usage is pretty much the same, save for the lack of `nbit`:

```c
void I32NR(int32_t *data, uint32_t size) {
    int32_t mask, head;
    struct {
        uint32_t init, size, nbit, edge;
    } heap[32];

    heap[0].nbit = 32;
    heap[0].size = size;
    heap[0].init = head = 0;
    do {
        size = heap[head].init - 1;
        mask = 1 << ((heap[head].nbit & 0x7F) - 1);
        heap[head].edge = heap[head].size;
        while (++size < heap[head].edge)
            if (data[size] & mask)
                while (size < --heap[head].edge)
                    if (~data[heap[head].edge] & mask) {
                        data[size] ^= data[heap[head].edge];
                        data[heap[head].edge] ^= data[size];
                        data[size] ^= data[heap[head].edge];
                        break;
                    }
        heap[head].nbit = ((heap[head].nbit & 0x7F) - 1)
                        |  (heap[head].nbit & 0x80);
        if ((heap[head].nbit & 0x7F) && (heap[head].edge > 1)) {
            heap[head + 1] = heap[head];
            heap[head + 1].size = heap[head].edge;
            heap[++head].nbit |= 0x80;
            continue;
        }
        do {
            if ((heap[head].nbit & 0x7F)
            &&  (heap[head].size - heap[head].edge > 1)) {
                heap[head + 1] = heap[head];
                heap[head + 1].init = heap[head].edge;
                heap[++head].nbit &= 0x7F;
                break;
            }
            while ((head >= 0) && !(heap[head--].nbit & 0x80));
        } while (head >= 0);
    } while (head >= 0);
}
```

Comment: Great! I'll look into in-place radix sort. I haven't heard of it before.

Comment: @frederick99 This is a nice keyword / algorithm-class which offers many possibilities. but keep in mind, that this won't apply to the problem-formulation in this exact form (as there is nothing told about bounds on the elements / bit-representation size of these).

Comment: @sascha, according to the example given in the OP post, the elements are implied to be numeric… At least I understood it that way.

Comment: @sascha The elements are integers, 32-bit most probably.

Comment: This is one *important assumption*. Everythings good then. Before that statement, it was just an example.

Comment: @sascha Thinking of it now, won't radix sort work for strings too? :\

Comment: @frederick99, it will, sure, but its asymptotic complexity would be far greater than linear, as long as strings are generally not limited in length.

Comment: The k is now a non-constant depending on those strings.

Comment: How do I compare the bits without creating a second array to hold the binary representations? Do I convert them to binary on the go?

Comment: @frederick99, each standard integer in computer memory is already stored as binary. All you need to extract its M-th bit is to [AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.22.26.22) it with (1 << M) and check if the result is 0. If it\`s not, the bit is 1, otherwise it is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `ar[i]=j`, check whether `ar[j]` is negative or not, if negative remove `ar[i]` else replace element `ar[j]` with `-ar[j]`.

NOTE : This will work only if all the elements are positive and elements lies within `0<=elements<array_size`.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
       int elem1 = ar[i];
       int elem2 = ar[Math.abs(elem1)];
       if(elem2 >= 0) {
           ar[Math.abs(elem1)] = -elem2;
       }
       else {
           //elem1 already exists in an array. remove elem1 or copy distinct elements to another array
       }
    }
```

Comment: It raises java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Can you include what you are trying to do?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException will come if elements are not in the range of array size as i already mentioned.

Comment: No, it is because you make the elements negative and don't handle it in your code. I wanted to know if you could modify your code and make it work.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! :D