# Is this a O(n^2) runtime or a O(n)?

Tags: javascript, big-o

I am confused. I am solving this problem on leetcode and I wrote this code where there's nested while loops. From the first look, one would think it is an O(N^2) solution, however, I am wondering if that is true since the inner while loop does not iterate over the entire array but just a part of it. Thus, I think it is O(N).

Please confirm my understanding

```
 var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let i = 0, j = i + 1
   
    while(i < nums.length - 1 && j < nums.length){
        while(nums[i] == nums[j]){
            nums.splice(j, 1)
        }

        j++
        i++
    }
    
    return j
};
```

Comment: Easiest way is to measure on different inputs and plot graph

Comment: Easy way to find out: Test for various values of *N*, like 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc. going up by a factor of 10 each time. You'll very quickly find out the performance characteristics.

Comment: If you're always incrementing both `i` and `j` identically maybe you really just need one variable `i` and use `i + 1` in place of `j`.

Comment: how does removing variable j optimize the solution or help it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's `O(n)`. Given a length of L, The outer loop iterates L times (worst-case), and the inner loop also iterates a *total* of L times (worst-case, in case all elements in the array are duplicates).

O(n) + O(n) = O(n).

Comment: This assumes O(splice) = O(1).  I don't know if that is true.  I suspect it's O(n) then O(removeDuplicates) = On^2)

Comment: how would you determine the time complexity of the splice operation?

Answer (score 0):

@CertainPerformance already did the heavy work to convince us that the worst case that `nums.splice(j, 1)` runs at most O(n) times when nums consist of all duplicates.

O(splice) = O(n) per [JavaScript runtime complexity of Array functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614237/javascript-runtime-complexity-of-array-functions). This makes sense to me, worst case we remove 1 element at j = 2 means we need to copy n - 2 elements, then n - 3 etc.

O(removeDuplicates) = O(n^2)

You can make it O(nlogn) by sorting the list, then iterate through the sorted list and push the current value to a result list if it is different then the last one.  O(n) is if you radix sort.

See also [Remove duplicates from array in linear time and without extra arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414854/remove-duplicates-from-array-in-linear-time-and-without-extra-arrays) (note, some of these answer use O(n) space so they are not valid answers to that question).